# Nextjs in Production

Tags: next.js

I know that Next.js can do SSR.
I have questions about production.

In my experience(no SSR). Frontend build static files, and then give the folder to backend to integrate.And there is only one server.

I want to know that if we want to use SSR with Next.js (not static site).

1. Do we need host two server? One for host backend(nodes, java…), another for host frontned(next.js)?
2. If I use nodejs as backend language.Can I write all api in next.js?(I mean frontend and backend code all use next.js, so that there is only one server).
3. If question one's answer is yes, I see the document use `next start` to host server, is it strong enough to host many users?

Comment: You can we different servers for your backend or frontend. Or you can use same server for frontend and backend just you need to send your server static files back to the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do we need host two server? One for host backend(nodes, java…), another for host > frontned(next.js)?

In most cases you would have a single server producing the SSR as well as rendering the markup required for the client. The associated Javascript files that only the browser can be sent via a asset serving server ( e.g: An S3 bucket ) - You would front the whole thing using a CDN so your server would not get all public requests

> If I use nodejs as backend language.Can I write all api in next.js?(I mean  frontend and backend code all use next.js, so that there is only one server).

Yes, for simplistic uses you can checkout the api solve that NextJS ships with. https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction

> If question one's answer is yes, I see the document use next start to host ? server, is it strong enough to host many users?

You would use a next build and next start - With the latest optimizations nextjs adds Static site generation (SSG)  - Sorry one more confusing term but this lets your *backend* nodejs app receive much lesser requests and be smart about serving repetitive requests, However even with these abilities you should front the whole thing using a CDN to ensure high availability and low operating costs.